# Permissions on example payment method- Drupal commerce

Tags: users, commerce

This is probably something simple, but I'm having a hard time configuring the permissions that would only allow the administrators to see the example payment method of the Drupal Commerce module. I have example payment method activated for testing purposes but every time I activate it, the example payment methods appears public. How can I configure the permission so that only the administrators can see the example payment method. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to go admin/commerce/config/payment-methods
And edit the example payment. In there you can set a condition that is on user. Data type of current user is admin and that will only allow admins to process the test payments.

Answer (score 0):

@topCweb shows the way.  In terms of details, here is an export of the condition that I ended up using.  The "User has role(s)" condition seemed the easiest.  The exact role number may vary for each site.

```
 "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "3" : "3" } },
          "operation" : "OR"
        }
      }
    ],
```